# Union 2 datasets in Google Cloud Data Fusion

Tags: google-cloud-platform, pipeline, google-cloud-data-fusion

I receive regular data uploads from 2 sources that submit their data in the same structure (same columns etc). I am trying to create a pipeline within Data Fusion that will combine this data into 1 table. Is there any way to do this? I see a similar question, but given that it was asked and answered a decade ago I imagine the platform has changed quite a bit so I hope this is okay to ask.

I've tried using a join and just setting every column in one dataset equal to the same column in the other, but to no avail. The final product has null rows equaling to the number of rows in the dataset whose columns were unchecked, while the dataset with the checked columns has its data intact.

None of the other tools in fusion seem useful for this, but it is unbelievable to me that it isn't possible.

I appreciate whatever help you may be able to provide!